# Binding Data to Blend visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, blend

I have made a UI using Blend for visual studio 2015. This UI containts a button and a datagrid.

I Binded the first 2 columns of it using Blend options. the XAML of the grid looks like this:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43.75" Margin="43.336,38.266,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="114.037" Click="button_Click"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="72.025,115.725,21.102,26.123" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource Property1Template}" Header="Property1"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Property2}" Header="Property2"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

whenever i open the UI thats what i get and its good:

[image]

However, i have made a code behind this where i want to add columns to this grid using ItemSource like this:

```
for (int z=0; z < list_Exp.Count; z++)
{

var d = new MyDataObject();
d.AmountNeed = (goalexp - currentexp) / Convert.ToInt32(list_Exp[z]);
d.TotalLose = d.AmountNeed * (list_Amount_MadeFrom_One[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_One[z] + list_Amount_MadeFrom_Two[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_Two[z]);
d.TotalGain = d.AmountNeed * list_AmountMade[z] * list_SellPrice[z];
d.TotalCost = d.TotalGain - d.TotalLose;

L.Add(d);


}
dataGrid.ItemsSource = L;
```

The result i get is once i click the button the columns of `Property1` and `Property2` disappear and it wont show me the other coulmns i wanted it to show.

My goal is to keep first 2 columns as they are and just to add 4 new ones at location 3-6.

Thank You.